# How to get data from SQL Database using bundles, Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-activity

So basically I have ListView and a second activity with two EditText that are holding data (kinda like the notes application). The ListView shows them created but When I click an item in the ListView it shows a blank second activity without the data. I've tried multiple ways of using bundles to fix this but so far it still shows nothing.

Here's what I currently have for my first activity (ListView Activity)...

```
    List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivityPlanes.this, MainActivityPaper.class);

            public static final String keyname = "android.application.project.planes.MainActivityPlanes.Extra_keyname1";
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            String keyname = title1.getText().toString();
            String key = text1.getText().toString(); 
            b.putString("Extra__keyname", keyname);
            b.putString("Extra__key", key);
            launchActivity.putExtras(b);

            startActivity(launchActivity);
```

Here's my second piece of code for the bundle in my second activity (the activity holding the two TextViews)...

```
    Intent launchActvity = getIntent();

    Bundle b = launchActvity.getExtras();

    String keyname = launchActvity.getStringExtra(MainActivityPlanes.Extra_keyname);
    String key = launchActvity.getStringExtra(MainActivityPlanes.Extra_key);

    TextView title1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    title1.setText("keyname");
    text1.setText("key");
```

any idea on how to fix this?

First Activity

```
 package android.application.project.planes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivityPlanes extends Activity {

Button Add;
ListView List;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_planes);

    Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {

        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), MainActivityPaper.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

    });

    List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivityPlanes.this, MainActivityPaper.class);

             Bundle b = new Bundle();
             String keyname = title1.getText().toString();
             String key = text1.getText().toString(); 
             b.putString("Extra__keyname", keyname);
             b.putString("Extra__key", key);
             launchActivity.putExtras(b);

             startActivity(launchActivity);

        }

    });

    MainActivityChampagne info = new MainActivityChampagne(this);       
    info.open();        
    ArrayList<String> data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    List.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

}
```

Second Activity

```
package android.application.project.planes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivityPaper extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView text1, title1;
Button save1, update1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_paper);

    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    save1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    update1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    save1.setOnClickListener(this);
    update1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.button3:

        String titles = title1.getText().toString();
        String notes = text1.getText().toString();

        MainActivityChampagne entry = new MainActivityChampagne(MainActivityPaper.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(titles, notes);
        entry.close();

        break;

    case R.id.button5:

        String thetitles = title1.getText().toString();
        String thenotes = text1.getText().toString();

        MainActivityChampagne up = new MainActivityChampagne(MainActivityPaper.this);
        up.open();
        up.updateEntry(thetitles, thenotes);
        up.close();

        break;

    }

    Intent launchActvity = getIntent();

    Bundle b = launchActvity.getExtras();

    String keyname = launchActvity.getStringExtra("keyname");
    String key = launchActvity.getStringExtra("key");

    TextView title1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    title1.setText("keyname");
    text1.setText("key");

}

}
```

My Third Activity (SQL Database Activity)...

```
 package android.application.project.planes;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MainActivityChampagne extends Activity {

public static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
public static final String KEY_NOTES = "lastcall";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Champagnedb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "champagneTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub\
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}

public MainActivityChampagne(Context c){
    ourContext = c;

}

public MainActivityChampagne open(){
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();

}

public long createEntry(String titles, String notes) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, titles);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public ArrayList<String> getData() {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_NAME };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iNotes = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

    ArrayList<String> string_array = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())

    {

        result = c.getString (iNotes) + "\n";
        string_array.add(result);

        }

    return string_array;

}

public void updateEntry(String thetitles, String thenotes) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, thetitles);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NOTES, thenotes);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "=" + thetitles + KEY_NOTES + "=" + thenotes, null);

}

 }
```

LogCat

```
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-23 15:42:19.710: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-23 15:42:19.710: W/ActivityManager(284): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40d605b0
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d11750 that was originally bound here
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d11750 that was originally bound here
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-23 15:42:19.729: E/ActivityThread(638):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638): null
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d11750 that was originally bound here
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-23 15:42:19.858: E/StrictMode(638):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-23 15:42:19.889: W/ActivityManager(284): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40db5f30
06-23 15:42:19.889: D/dalvikvm(638): GC_CONCURRENT freed 466K, 20% free 2493K/3080K, paused 75ms+84ms, total 272ms
```

Comment: It looks like your key don't match? or thats just a sample

Comment: this is my code, where do you see a miss match?

Comment: when you do a putString you used key "Extra__keyname" and when you get string you used key "keyname" only. Although looking at android bundle reference there is only getString instead of getStringExtra.

Comment: @Faisal when I change it to getString it marks it as an error and tells me to set it to getStringExtra.

Comment: Ohh oops I missed it, you are using launchActivity instead of b.getString

Comment: still can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Found it should be:

```
Bundle b = launchActivity.getExtras();

String keyname = b.getString("keyname");
String key = b.getString("key");
```

and you probably need to remove Extra__

Comment: my two strings "keyname " and "key" are not being used and in my first activity "              String keyname = title1.getText().toString();
              String key = text1.getText().toString();" the title1 and text1 are being marked wrong. title1 and text1 are the two edittext from activity two.

Comment: I assumed you assign it the value, well you'll have to get the value from the list view item. The easiest would be to assign it on listView getView with: setTag(yourViewHolder); then yourViewHolder = (YourViewHolder) arg1.getTag(); then you should have access to the views on that tag. Then use that like yourViewHolder.title1.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is here:

```
b.putString("Extra__keyname", keyname);
b.putString("Extra__key", key);
```

and here:

```
String keyname = launchActivity.getStringExtra("keyname");
String key = launchActivity.getStringExtra("key");
```

you are trying to retrieve a StringExtra with a String that wasn't use in your first Activity (you used `"Extra__keyname" and "Extra__key"` in second Activity you must use these specific strings, plus as a good practice the "key" String for extra should be a public constant in your first Activity and then use the same constant in second Activity for getStringExtra, something like this:

```
 public static final String EXTRA_KEY_NAME = "com.example.yourclass.EXTRA_KEY_NAME";
```

this goes in your first Activity, then you put the extra like this:

```
 b.putString(EXTRA_KEY_NAME, keyname);
```

then on your second Activity you get your Extra like this:

```
 launchActivity.getStringExtra(FirstActivity.EXTRA_KEY_NAME);
```

this is a better approach in programming terms and recommended by google, sorry for my english, Regards.

Comment: I tried putting it in the code but it didnt work, but again I dont think I did it right.

Comment: with the code you are providing the problem stand in `those` parts i specify, maybe your problem isn't in the Bundle or Intent part but in the ListView, or TextView where the Data will be show, provide the whole first and second Activity code to check.

Comment: ok, as what i saw the problem is exactly what im explaining in my answer, you are trying to retrieve in second Activity on methods `getStringExtra("keyname") and getStringExtra("key")` with wrong strings, of course they will come null since there is nothing in the `Bundle` object with those strings as a key, change second Activity on these parts to `getStringExtra("Extra__keyname") and getStringExtra("Extra__key")`, plus, try to read something about `Naming Convention in Java` and re-read my answer to understand where is the problem and the propper solution.

Comment: can you check my first and second code box above to see if they are correct?

Comment: i did check those, again did you understand my answer? i repeat again where is the problem if you do this in First Activity `b.putString("Extra__keyname", keyname); and b.putString("Extra__key", key);`then to get the strings in Second Activity you must do `String keyname = launchActvity.getStringExtra("Extra__keyname");
String key = launchActvity.getStringExtra("Extra__key");` please again, let me know what don't you understand from my answer, regards.

Answer (score 0):

change your first activity code to

```
package android.application.project.planes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivityPlanes extends Activity {

Button Add;
ListView List;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_planes);

    Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {

        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), MainActivityPaper.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

    });

    List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivityPlanes.this, MainActivityPaper.class);

             Bundle b = new Bundle();
             String keyname =                   ((TextView)arg1.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
             //String key = text1.getText().toString(); 
             b.putString("Extra__keyname", keyname);
            //b.putString("Extra__key", key);
             launchActivity.putExtras(b);

             startActivity(launchActivity);

        }

    });

    MainActivityChampagne info = new MainActivityChampagne(this);       
    info.open();        
    ArrayList<String> data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    List.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

}
```

change your second activity class to

```
package android.application.project.planes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivityPaper extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView text1, title1;
Button save1, update1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_paper);

    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    save1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    update1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);


    Intent launchActvity = getIntent();

    Bundle b = launchActvity.getExtras();

    String keyname = b.getString("Extra__keyname");
   //this string same as b.putString("Extra__keyname", keyname);
   // String key = b.getString("Extra__key");

    TextView title1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    title1.setText(keyname);
    //text1.setText(key);

    save1.setOnClickListener(this);
    update1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.button3:

        String titles = title1.getText().toString();
        String notes = text1.getText().toString();

        MainActivityChampagne entry = new MainActivityChampagne(MainActivityPaper.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(titles, notes);
        entry.close();

        break;

    case R.id.button5:

        String thetitles = title1.getText().toString();
        String thenotes = text1.getText().toString();

        MainActivityChampagne up = new MainActivityChampagne(MainActivityPaper.this);
        up.open();
        up.updateEntry(thetitles, thenotes);
        up.close();

        break;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: text1 and title1 in the first activity get marked as an error saying "Multiple markers at this line
 - Duplicate local variable 
  keyname
 - title1 cannot be resolved"

Comment: these are the lines String keyname = title1.getText().toString();
             String key = text1.getText().toString();

Comment: it told me to change getStringExtra to just getString and when I did it cleared all errors and warnings but I'm not sure that's correct because 1st activity still has errors

Comment: it worked only for the title (title1 is the variable name for editText3, which is the title box) but what can I do to get the body (editText1, text1) to display?

Comment: so use this keyname and get details in the second activity from the database

Comment: whenever I try to click the add button it crashes my application

Comment: the problem is coming from activity two --->  Intent launchActvity = getIntent();

     Bundle b = launchActvity.getExtras();

     String keyname = b.getString("Extra__keyname");
     String key = b.getString("Extra__key");

     TextView title1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
     TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

     title1.setText(keyname);
     text1.setText(key);

Comment: you havent passed "key" from first activity so you can't access if from second activity